# CSV file importing with special non-ASCII characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently importing a CSV file and saving the values. Those values can contain non-ASCII values such as `™`, `®` and many others, which cause the file to fail to be parsed. Is there a way around this?

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
  Yadda yadda
end
```

The file contents are breaking `foreach`.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are accessible and reading in from the CSV you can use a helper like this:

```
  def ascii_only(string)
    encoding_options = {
        :invalid           => :replace,  # Replace invalid byte sequences
        :undef             => :replace,  # Replace anything not defined in ASCII
        :replace           => '',        # Use a blank for those replacements
        :UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR => true       # Always break lines with \n
    }
    string.encode Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of Ruby you are on. I am assuming it is 1.9.3 or greater.

Try using this to [force encoding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) that your CSV file is saved in

```
 force_encoding(encoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't duplicate the problem on Ruby 1.9.3 or 2.0. I wrote this test code:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('test.csv') do |row|
  puts row
end
```

And created this test.csv file:

```
char
™
®
```

Running the code correctly displays the characters.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is write a custom CSV converter, and then reference that converter in your options hash when you call foreach.

Custom converter:

```
  #define custom converter to eliminate non ASCII characters
  CSV::Converters[:only_ascii] = lambda{|s| 
    begin 
      s.force_encoding("utf-8").encode("utf-8", "binary", :replace => "", :undef => :replace, :invalid => :replace)
    rescue
      s
    end
  }
```

And then in your options hash:

```
   CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, converters: [:only_ascii]) do |row|
     Yadda yadda
   end
```

Now, if you want to replace them with reasonable ASCII equivalents instead of blanks, you can write a custom function to do this and then in your custom converter where it says :replace => "", you would do :replace => you_custom_method_name_here.